# Key not found when loading CCArmature object

Tags: android, cocos2d-x

When I'm loading the CCArmature object, it occurs this error

```
06-08 22:47:33.447: D/cocos2d-x debug info(7645): Assert failed: key not found : <integer/real>
06-08 22:47:33.447: E/cocos2d-x assert(7645): e:\Working\cocos2dx\projects\Viking\proj.android\../cocos2d/cocos/2d/platform/CCFileUtils.cpp function:textHandler line:296
```

I know the root is from plist file path. However, I don't know what's wrong because it works perfectly when I change this armature by another armature. In addition, I found out when I put the plist file at the resource (don't put it in any subfolder), it also works fine. I check the path many times, but the error still happens.

Do you have any suggestion?

```
ArmatureDataManager::getInstance()->addArmatureFileInfo("gfx/Ammo10.png", "gfx/Ammo10.plist", "gfx/Ammo1.ExportJson"); //This CANNOT works

//ArmatureDataManager::getInstance()->addArmatureFileInfo("gfx/Ammo10.png", "Ammo10.plist", "gfx/Ammo1.ExportJson"); //But this can work

auto mBullet = CCArmature::create("Ammo1");

mBullet->setPosition(ccp(origin.x + visibleSize.width*0.5, origin.y + visibleSize.height*0.5));
this->addChild(mBullet, 7);
```

Comment: Your two lines above look identical. You say one works but one doesn't

Comment: @GameDeveloper Well, I discovered that if I put ArmatureDataManager::getInstance()->addArmatureFileInfo("gfx/Ammo10.png", "gfx/Ammo10.plist", "gfx/Ammo1.ExportJson"); at the init function (load resource at first) and use it after that, it works fine with both lines. However, I don't know why

Answer (score 0):

Open editor.
Open plist file.
Save plist. UTF-8 OR ANSI

Comment: You mean, OP should convert the plist to UTF-8 or plain ANSI?